# How to connect (FTP) to remote server via my Ubuntu VPS

Tags: server, ssh, vpn, ftp, tunnel

My problem is quite specific: I need to connect (FTP) to a client's server from my PC (Ubuntu 16.10) but my PC has dynamic IP and the client's server has IP filtering on. I have my own VPS (Ubuntu 16.04) obviously with static IP so I was thinking to tunnel my connection to client's server through my VPS. Preferably using FireFTP if possible. The only access I have to clients server will be FTP (possibly SFTP) and I can get my IP (my VPS's IP) to be added into the white list.

The problem is I am quite new to SSH (I own the VPS just for a few days) and SSH Tunneling seams to me quite higher level and my case seams to be quite specific. I don't mind studying this subject a bit, I just need to be pointed the right way (e.g. what type of SSH Tunnel I need an so on).

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find an answer to my question here: https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html. The tutorial if for firefox but it works well for FTP trafic too.

First you need to create SOCKS 5:

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 2121 user@yourvpsip
```

`2121` - this is selected port number. You can probably use any port but for forts between 0 and 1023 you need to use `sudo` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports))

`user@yourvpsip` - this is obvious - your username on your VPS server followed by your VPS ip (e.g. `user@123.123.123.123`)

Next (and last) step is to set up your FTP client to use PROXY

```
Proxy type: SOCKS 5
Proxy host: 127.0.0.1 (this is localhost IP)
Proxy port: 2121 (or replace with port you selected in first step)
```

On FileZilla you can find this settings in: Edit > Preferences > Connection > Generic proxy.

After you finish using it you might want to change the settings back because this only works when the SOCKS 5 is started from terminal.

If you have any additional questions please ask.